# didDiscoverPeripheral not been called after advertising another iOS device

Tags: ios, objective-c, cbcentralmanager, cbperipheral

basically i have two apps, one for scanning for bluetooth devices and the other for advertising, and what i am trying to do is to get a list of all iOS devices, within my proximity on the app which scans for the iOS device .

This is my code so far:

**Scanning.m:**

```
// Scan for all available CoreBluetooth LE devices
    NSDictionary *scanOptions = @{CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey:@(YES)};
    NSArray *services = @[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"1CC024D6-E413-4B56-993C-831CAF033366"]];

    [self.centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:services options:scanOptions];

- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
{
    NSLog(@"RSSI: %d", [RSSI intValue]);

}

// method called whenever the device state changes.
- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central
{
    // Determine the state of the peripheral
    if ([central state] == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOff) {
        NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is powered off");
    }
    else if ([central state] == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn) {
        NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is powered on and ready");
    }
    else if ([central state] == CBCentralManagerStateUnauthorized) {
        NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth BLE state is unauthorized");
    }
    else if ([central state] == CBCentralManagerStateUnknown) {
        NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth BLE state is unknown");
    }
    else if ([central state] == CBCentralManagerStateUnsupported) {
        NSLog(@"CoreBluetooth BLE hardware is unsupported on this platform");
    }
}
```

**Advertising.m:**

```
    self.peripheralManager = [[CBPeripheralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];
    [self listenForRelays];


    /** Required protocol method.  A full app should take care of all the possible states,
 *  but we're just waiting for  to know when the CBPeripheralManager is ready
 */
- (void)peripheralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheral
{

    if (peripheral.state == CBPeripheralManagerStatePoweredOn)
    {

        // We're in CBPeripheralManagerStatePoweredOn state...
        NSLog(@"self.peripheralManager powered on.");

        // ... so build our service.

    }
}


-(void) listenForRelays {

    if(self.peripheralManager.state == CBPeripheralManagerStatePoweredOn)
    {

        NSDictionary *advertisingData = @{CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey:@"my-peripheral",
                                          CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey:@[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"1CC024D6-E413-4B56-993C-831CAF033322"]]};

        // Start advertising over BLE
        [self.peripheralManager startAdvertising:advertisingData];
    }

}
```

When i run the different apps on different iphones, nothing happens !

This doesn't crash but `didDiscoverPeripheral` never gets called :( please help me out ! and yes i have gone through the documentation but still no good :((

cheers

Comment: You can't initiate your scan until after you are in the powered-on state - use code in your scanning app similar to that which is in your advertising app

Comment: @Paulw11 OMGGGGG !!!! Thanks so much, your a genius ! been on this for the past 3 hours now, life saver !!!!

Answer (score 4):

You can't initiate your scan until after you are in the powered-on state - use code in your scanning app similar to that which is in your advertising app.

In iOS 7 starting the scan before you were powered on issued a warning on the console, but it still worked.  In iOS 8 it doesn't work.